# Using singletons for data fetch in swift

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

I have been using  `URLSession.shared.dataTask` to perform the API calls from my application. I'm just confused about how singletons function. As far as I understand there is just one instance of singleton and in this case only one instance of `urlSession`. Now the below code snippet will cause 3 async calls, however, we just have one instance of `dataTask`. Does that mean we see serial behavior here?

```
["1","2","3"].forEach {
     loadImage(url: $0) {
     print("image Successfully cached")
      }
}

   func loadImage(url:String, _ completion: @escaping ()->()){
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) {[weak self] (data,response,error) in
           print("starting \(url) Thread.current")
           Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: Double.random(in: 0...3))
           if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse , response.statusCode == 200 {
               let image = UIImage(data: data!)
               self?.imageCache.setObject(image!, forKey: url as NSString)
               completion()
           } else {
               print("finishing \(url) Thread.current")
               completion()
           }
       }.resume()
   }
```

The output of my playground

```
starting 1 <NSThread: 0x6000037e8ec0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
finishing 1 <NSThread: 0x6000037e8ec0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
image Successfully cached
starting 2 <NSThread: 0x6000037d3380>{number = 4, name = (null)}
finishing 2 <NSThread: 0x6000037d3380>{number = 4, name = (null)}
image Successfully cached
starting 3 <NSThread: 0x6000037d3380>{number = 4, name = (null)}
finishing 3 <NSThread: 0x6000037d3380>{number = 4, name = (null)}
image Successfully cached
```

Comment: `URLSession.shared` is a singleton but dataTask will be enqueued and finish asynchronously.

Comment: Updated question to post playground output

Comment: Playgrounds don't multi-thread unless you enable it explicitly.

Comment: But from the above output, you could see that it is multithreading

Comment: and I'm seeing serial behavior rather than concurrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the completion handler called serially. The network requests run on multiple threads, but they converge to a single point to execute their completion handlers.

The handlers run on the `delegateQueue`, specified as part of the URLSessionConfiguration if you're not using the `shared` session https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411597-init

Each time you call `Thread.sleep`, this completely blocks the queue from executing, it doesn't free it up for the other items on the queue to run, because by default the queue runs one job at a time on a single thread.

Without seeing the network request, it's probably just a coincidence that all 3 requests finish in order, and their completion handlers get put onto the queue in the same order.

Comment: So, are you saying that the queue that runs the completion handlers is a serial queue?

Comment: Yes, unless you configure it with your own delegateQueue setup for more concurrency.

Comment: Cool. That makes sense.Thanks